# How to write jsdocs comments for typescript interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using jsdocs for commenting my code. I am a bit puzzled how to comment properly.

for example, I have such interfaces:

```
export interface IModal {
  onClose: () => void;
  isOpen: boolean;
  id: number;
  deleteSelectedId: () => void;
  isDepartment: boolean;
}

export interface IAccountsValue {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  middlename: string;
  department: string;
  id: number | null;
}


export interface IGetValue {
  name: string;
  value: string;
  id: number;
}
```

How to write comments for that properly ?

Comment: What do you mean _"properly"_? What information are you hoping to add, for whose benefit?

Comment: "Properly" I mean,  as I know, there are specific rules how to write comments. And I wanted to find out how to follow all these rules . For example, if it is function, comments jsdocs have to look certain way and so on

Comment: What specific issue/s are you facing that the JSDoc docs don't cover?